# change the color of disabled h:selectBooleanCheckbox to black

Tags: html, css, richfaces, jsf-1.2

I am using richfaces and jsf 1.2. i want to change the color of disabled h:selectBooleanCheckbox to black. I have tried:

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{supplier.carrier}" disabled="true" style="color: #000000"/>
```

and

```
<span style="color:#000000;">
                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{supplier.carrier}" disabled="true" style="color: #000000"/>
                </span>
```

but they are not working. anyone got any clue? thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a checkbox, what color are you trying to change? (Also the checkbox is not a RichFaces component).

Comment: thanks for commenting, its in the title, from grey to black.

Comment: So background then? That can't be directly styled as far as I know.

Comment: i mean the tick color, thanks

Comment: Same deal, the appearance of the checkbox depends on your OS/browser, it's not directly stylable.